# Add and Remove Marker For Polygon Shape Change on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am Trying Google Map Drawing Tools For the First time So If You Notice any Wrong method or etc then you can point it out.

Basically, I am working on Adding and Removing marker depend on the shape which user draw on the map or after editing the shape or readjust it.

I use three shapes for it. 1. Circle 2. Rectangle 3. Polygon

Circle and Rectangle Works Fine. Just the Polygon doesn't work properly.
Polygon Doesn't show or remove marker properly after drawing and after editing it.

Here is the Code for the circle which is working Fine.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControl: false
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(null);
        redondo = circle;
        google.maps.event.addListener(redondo, 'radius_changed', function () {

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (!(circle.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())))
                {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    $('#prop' + i).hide();
                } else {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                    $('#prop' + i).show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Now For Polygon: Which Is Not Working Properly.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {

        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControl: false
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(null);
        redondo = polygon;
        google.maps.event.addListener(redondo, 'bounds', function () {

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if((polygon.map.center.lat() < markers[i].getPosition().lat()) && (polygon.map.center.lng() < markers[i].getPosition().lng()))
                {
                 markers[i].setMap(map);
                $('#prop' + i).show();
            } else {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                    $('#prop' + i).hide();
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You circle isn't working, you are checking the bounds of the circle, which is a square, not a circle.

Comment: Sir @geocodezip , my circle works fine. I can add and remove marker on drawing circle and also on editing the shape after drawing.

Comment: @geocodezip Sir I am doing it for the 1st time so I take the google map references for it.  this is the link. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer

Comment: @geocodezip sir, I am trying this for the first time and I follow the google map samples and drawing library example and snippet so it may possible that I have done some mistake or not follow some rules and regulations of doing it but a downvote is not motivating at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Make this arrays.

```
 circleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#2A5C8D',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        },
        rectangleOptions: {
            fillColor: '#2A5C8D',
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1
        }
```

Then Using Google Drawing Tools Api

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {

        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControl: false
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(null);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (!(circle.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())))
            {
                markers[i].setMap(null);
                $('#prop' + i).hide();
            } else {
                markers[i].setMap(map);
                $('#prop' + i).show();

            }
        }

    });

     google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        drawingManager.setOptions({
            drawingControl: false
        });
        drawingManager.setMap(null);
        redondo = circle;
        google.maps.event.addListener(redondo, 'radius_changed', function () {

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (!(circle.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())))
                {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    $('#prop' + i).hide();
                } else {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                    $('#prop' + i).show();
                }
            }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(redondo, 'center_changed', function () {

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (!(circle.getBounds().contains(markers[i].getPosition())))
                {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                    $('#prop' + i).hide();
                } else {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                    $('#prop' + i).show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

This is For Circle, Same Goes for rectangle. 
Hope this Will Work.

Comment: How to get  the bounded area by polygon ?

Comment: https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/placing-markers-inside-google-maps-polygons-855552210e4b  look at this